# Get a value from JSON from C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to get a value from a JSON file using C#. The JSON file looks more like the below string.

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "address_components": [
                {
                    "long_name": "3",
                    "short_name": "3",
                    "types": [
                        "street_number"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "formatted_address": "3, Puppalaguda - Manikonda Main Rd, Sri Laxmi Nagar Colony, Manikonda, Hyderabad, Telangana 500089, India",
            "geometry": {
                "bounds": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 17.4025788,
                        "lng": 78.3748307
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 17.4019665,
                        "lng": 78.3733937
                    }
                },
                "location": {
                    "lat": 17.4023166,
                    "lng": 78.37417409999999
                },
                "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED",
                "viewport": {
                    "northeast": {
                        "lat": 17.4036216302915,
                        "lng": 78.37546118029151
                    },
                    "southwest": {
                        "lat": 17.4009236697085,
                        "lng": 78.3727632197085
                    }
                }
            },
            "place_id": "EmkzLCBQdXBwYWxhZ3VkYSAtIE1hbmlrb25kYSBNYWluIFJkLCBTcmkgTGF4bWkgTmFnYXIgQ29sb255LCBNYW5pa29uZGEsIEh5ZGVyYWJhZCwgVGVsYW5nYW5hIDUwMDA4OSwgSW5kaWE",
            "types": [
                "street_address"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am looking for the **formatted_address** element from the JSON from C#. I am getting lost in JObject, JArray, JToken. I am trying to use NewtonSoft JSON.

Comment: Can you show some code please and also precise what library do you use for Json parsing if you use any.

Comment: i am trying to use Newtonsoft JSON... updated my question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39276161/1070452

Answer (score 1):

Using the [LINQ-to-JSON API](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/linqtojson.htm) (JObjects) you can get the formatted address easily using the [`SelectToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectToken.htm) method:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
string address = (string)obj.SelectToken("results[0].formatted_address");
Console.WriteLine(address);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fdvqkl

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to have model objects and then call

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

With jsonString being your input. Then you can retrieve the formatted_address from the first array element like this like this:

```
var formattedAddress = rootObject.results[0].formatted_address;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

using `Newtonsoft.Json` nuget . and do something like that

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "{'results':[{'SwiftCode':'','City':'','BankName':'Deutsche    Bank','Bankkey':'10020030','Bankcountry':'DE'},{'SwiftCode':'','City':'10891    Berlin','BankName':'Commerzbank Berlin (West)','Bankkey':'10040000','Bankcountry':'DE'}]}";

        var resultObjects = AllChildren(JObject.Parse(json))
            .First(c => c.Type == JTokenType.Array && c.Path.Contains("results"))
            .Children<JObject>();

        foreach (JObject result in resultObjects)
        {
            foreach (JProperty property in result.Properties())
            {
                // do something with the property belonging to result
            }
        }
    }

    // recursively yield all children of json
    private static IEnumerable<JToken> AllChildren(JToken json)
    {
        foreach (var c in json.Children())
        {
            yield return c;
            foreach (var cc in AllChildren(c))
            {
                yield return cc;
            }
        }
    }
```

change `JTokenType.Array` to whatever the type u wish , also change the "results" to the property name you wish to extract